# PHP graphing with google charts

Tags: php

This is first ever time am trying out PHP charting. I've tried my hands with a variety of graphing modules that are available but I'm not able to get my graphing going. Here's what i'm after. I have a page on which on clicking a button, a new PHP page opens which has code to do a DB query & print the graph on that page(The new page opened). For no good reason, I've finally decided to stick with google charts for the charting. Upon researching on stack overflow, I found a code that was agreed by many to be fully functional but given my dumbness in this matter, I'm not able to get it going. Any help to get this going would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

    $ins1   =   $_GET["ins1"];
    $ins2   =   $_GET['ins2'];
    $ins3   =   $_GET['ins3'];
    $ins4   =   $_GET['ins4'];
    $ins5   =   $_GET['ins5'];
    $ins6   =   $_GET['ins6'];
    $ins7   =   $_GET['ins7'];

    $sql_1 = "select ab_date, count(ab_date) as COUNT_AB_DATE from TABLE1 where AB_NAME='$ins1' and ab_date between '$ins2' and '$ins3' group by ab_date";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
    $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("database");

    if ($dbcheck) {
        $arr1 = array();
        $arr2 = array();
        $chart_array = array();

        // Execute SQL
        $result = mysql_query($sql_1);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $arr2 = array_keys($row);
                $arr1 = array_values($row);
            }
        }

        for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++) {
            $chart_array[$i]=array((string)$arr2[$i],intval($arr1[$i]));
        }
    }


    $data=json_encode($chart_array);
        //echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    // Close DB conn
    mysqli_close($link);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>XLINT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {

              // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
             var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn("string", "AB_DATE");
                data.addColumn("number", "#AB");

                data.addRows(<?php $data ?>);

                ]); 
              var options = {
                   title: 'TREND OF AB',
                  is3D: 'true',
                  width: 800,
                  height: 600
                };
              // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
              //do not forget to check ur div ID
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('plot1'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main2>
            <div>
                <table id="tbl_format_1">
                    <tr bgcolor="">
                        <td colspan="3" id="th_format">
                            <b> <?php GRAPHS BELOW ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                    <div id="plot1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </main2>
    </body>
</html>

Could someone please help me t get this going?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
<?php foreach($testArray as $key=>$value): ?>
          ['<?php echo $key ?>', <?php echo $value ?>],
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

full function drawChart:

```
 function drawChart() {

    <?php $testArray = array('AB_DATE1' => 10,'AB_DATE2' => 20,'AB_DATE3' => 30,'AB_DATE4' => 40,'AB_DATE5' => 50,'AB_DATE6' =>60,'AB_DATE7' => 70,); ?>

    // Create our data table.
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      <?php foreach($testArray as $key=>$value): ?>
      ['<?php echo $key ?>', <?php echo $value ?>],
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

In place of $testArray insert your array. Adjust your array (array('AB_DATE1' => 10,'AB_DATE2' => 20,...)) or loop.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts

Comment: Thank you very much websky. Using your example, I worked out the solution. I very much appreciate your help. Thank you again.